# Beautiful problem about 11 statements

Tags: combinatorics, logic

11 pieces of paper are on a line. On each of them one of 11 statements is written (all are different on each paper):

1)No false pieces of paper to the left

2)Exactly 1 false paper to the left

3)Exactly 2 false papers to the left

..

11)Exactly 10 false papers to the left

What is the biggest possible number of simultaneously true statements?

I've tried splitting it into 2 cases: when 1) is true and when 1) is false. If it's true, then it's the leftmost of the papers. I'm not sure how to proceed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  each true statement is followed by a false one, as if (for example) statement 3 is true, you can't put it in the next slot as well.

Comment: by "followed" and "the next slot" you mean the one to the left?

Comment: No, the next one to the right

Comment: so the answer is 6, is it? I've constructed a case with 6 trues.

Comment: That is correct.  You can get the statements number 1 through 6 correct by placing them in the odd numbered slots in order, then distribute the rest any way you want.